# Frequent location data extraction

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

How to extract frequent location data from an iOS backup?

I'd like to use it to generate GPX (location+time) output and use it to tag my photos.

Does anyone tried to adress this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your photos should be tagged if taken by the phone. You can use [iPhone Backup Extractor](https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com) — it will show you location data and times, that your iPhone tagged a location, be that a photo, a message or something else, which may help you for what you are trying to do.

The other option may be to download your google maps timeline if you have this activated: https://www.google.com/maps/timeline

You can manually extract the frequent location data from here, but you will need to convert the files to something readable.

```
/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.routined/
```

Comment: Given OP is trying to tag their photos with location data, I'm guessing the photos weren't taken on an iOS device.

Comment: Thanks for the positive contribution JMY. It's not just photos that are location tagged....

Comment: Okay, that seems better.